# CREATE DATABASE...FOR ATTACH; "The path specified by [...] is not a valid directory"

Tags: sql-server

On SQL Server Express (local machine), I am attempting to ["restore" an `.mdf` + `.ldf` file combo](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63255/database-cannot-be-upgraded-because-it-is-read-only-or-has-read-only-files-make):

```
CREATE DATABASE Caterease_restore
ON (FILENAME='C:\Users\ssds\Documents\Caterease.mdf')
LOG ON (FILENAME='C:\Users\ssds\Documents\Caterease_log.ldf')
FOR ATTACH;
```

For some reason, SQL Server can't make sense of these filepaths:

> The path specified by "C:\Users\ssds\Documents\Caterease.mdf" is not in a valid directory.

I've double- and triple-checked the filepaths, and simply copied / pasted them from the file explorer bar for good measure. I'm logged into SQL Server Express with my local admin account, which has access to anything and everything.

Comment: Check the SQL Server Configuration Manager on the Instance Host; check that the Service is running under which user and permission. set it to system or local administrator

Comment: Why do you want to create the database in a user's documents directory? That isn't the right place for database files.

Comment: Is it a path local to the server or is it on your workstation? Server only has access to its locations. If its the same machine, does the SQL Server service account have access to that path (unlikely given it's a user folder)

Comment: This is all on my workstation. We had trouble with a remote SQL Server instance, and wanted to see if the .mdf and .ldf files still had any good data. I brought them to my workstation for temporary perusal.

Comment: Thanks--I'll put these in a proper place (accessible to sa) and try again.

Comment: @GrahamC did you try adding the service (NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER ?) in local administrator OR providing access for target path?
I am getting same error, if you have solution, please share.